# Error when trying to apply a function to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I've written a function that takes in a string and a dictionary then matches the key string to the keys in the dictionary, fairly standard stuff but I can't work out how to apply it to a dataframe here is the function i want to apply:

```
def key_check(d={}, key=''):
new = {}
if not key:
    return 
if key in d:
    new[key] = d[key]
else:
    new[key] = ''
return new
```

And I'm attempting to apply it like this:

```
df["centre"] = df["centre"].apply(key_check, axis=1, args=df["name"])
```

I'm getting this error but don't understand what could be ambiguous, the column name is either a string or a null value, the column centre is a dictionary. How can I fix this?

```
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:4433, in Series.apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4323 def apply(
   4324     self,
   4325     func: AggFuncType,
   (...)
   4328     **kwargs,
   4329 ) -> DataFrame | Series:
   4330     """
   4331     Invoke function on values of Series.
   4332 
   (...)
   4431     dtype: float64
   4432     """
-> 4433     return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:1065, in SeriesApply.__init__(self, obj, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs)
   1055 def __init__(
   1056     self,
   1057     obj: Series,
   (...)
   1061     kwargs,
   1062 ):
   1063     self.convert_dtype = convert_dtype
-> 1065     super().__init__(
   1066         obj,
   1067         func,
   1068         raw=False,
   1069         result_type=None,
   1070         args=args,
   1071         kwargs=kwargs,
   1072     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:119, in Apply.__init__(self, obj, func, raw, result_type, args, kwargs)
    117 self.obj = obj
    118 self.raw = raw
--> 119 self.args = args or ()
    120 self.kwargs = kwargs or {}
    122 if result_type not in [None, "reduce", "broadcast", "expand"]:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1527, in NDFrame.__nonzero__(self)
   1525 @final
   1526 def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1527     raise ValueError(
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: *I'm getting this error...* What error? Put it in the post.

Comment: `axis` is provided twice. I don't know if something else is happening (error is not posted), but you need to fix it.

Comment: Corrected the above, Axis is not in twice, that was a bad edit

Answer (score 1):

`df["centre"]` is a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`. It doesn't have an axis and its `apply` method doesn't have an `axis=...` parameter. Looking at its call signature [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply):

```
Series.apply(func, convert_dtype=True, args=(), **kwargs)
```

there is no "axis" parameter so it is relegated to `kwargs`. `args` is a `tuple` of positionals parameters to be used on each call to the applied function. But pandas has this strange line that causes you problems as seen in the stack trace

```
self.args = args or ()
```

Its trying to set a default for args if args is any falsy value. That seems like a bug to me. `args` defaults to a `tuple` and is defined to only take `tuple` so why this thing where things like `""`, `False` and `None` work? Anyway, this trips you up. You pass a `Series` for this parameter and that truth value test in the `or` causes the problem. But you shouldn't be passing a `Series` when you really want the positional arguments.

If you really wanted the `Series` for each call to `key_check`, you would do

```
df["centre"] = df["centre"].apply(key_check, args=(df["name"],))
```

But, cribbing off of Kevin Spaghetti's answer, I think you want a row-wise apply. And that means keeping "centre" and "name" as rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'centre': [{'one': 1}, {'two': 2}, {'three': 3}, {'fubar':4}],
    'name': ['one', 'two', '', 'four']
})

print(df)

print("=================================")

def key_check(row):
    key = row["name"]
    if key:
        return {key:row["centre"].get(key, "")}
    return None

df["centre"] = df[['centre', 'name']].apply(key_check, axis=1)

print(df)
```

OUTPUT

```
        centre  name
0    {'one': 1}   one
1    {'two': 2}   two
2  {'three': 3}      
3  {'fubar': 4}  four
=================================
        centre  name
0    {'one': 1}   one
1    {'two': 2}   two
2          None      
3  {'four': ''}  four
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the key argument in the function and you will see that it is not a single record but the whole column (a series).
This is why the `if not key` fails, because pandas does not implicitly convert the series to a truth value (this is why it tells you to use the `all()` and `any()` methods).

What i think you want to do is

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'centre': [{'one': 1}, {'two': 2}, {'three': 3}],
    'name': ['one', 'two', 'three']
})

def check(row):
  print(row['centre'])
  print(row['name'])

  return row['centre'][row['name']]

df[['centre', 'name']].apply(check, axis=1)
```

This allows apply to access every element of the current row (axis=1) and return a dictionary.

Comment: This was the bit I didn't understand, I don't know how to work with all() or any(), I don't understand what part of my code is failing.

Comment: You might start by applying a function that just returns its input and prints the arguments to see how the column that you selected is passed to your function.

Comment: It's printing out what I expected, a column of a dictionary and a column of a single string. I don't understand

Comment: @iFunction - Working code was posted here. If you do the same for your question and show us the output you get, then we can see what is going on. So far, its quite vague. For instance, is this guess about what your DF looks like correct?